# Cannot resolve method add(*.: Facebook Login to Android App

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-fragments

I am doing this tutorial:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2#step1

Except I am adding the facebook login to my current app instead of creating a new blank one.

I've just pasted the oncreate code into my oncreate method.

The button shows up fine but the issue I am having is that I am getting a Cannot Resolve Method error for this section of my oncreate method in my mainactivity class. The areas with the error are the ones wrapped with the ***.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                ***.add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)***
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = ***(MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);***
    }

    }
```

First Error: Cannot resolve method 'add(packagename.mainFragment)

Second error: Inconvertible types: cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'package.mainFragment'

Here's the whole class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    Button sendIPbutton; //Button for sending IP Address
    EditText mEdit; //Get info from what user enters in form
    //TextView mText;
    TextView coordinates;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        /*http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/*/
        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);





/**********************************************************************/
        /*get reference to views*/
        sendIPbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendIP);
        mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterIP);
        sendIPbutton.setOnClickListener(this);



//        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
//                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEdit.getWindowToken(), 0);
        /*add click listener to Button "sendIPbutton"*/
//        sendIPbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View arg0) {
//                //Add JSON Logic here
//
                String ip = "http://";
                ip = ip + ((mEdit).getText().toString()) + "/rpi/";
                System.out.println(ip);
                //String json = "{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = "";
                try {
                    //1. CREATE HTTPCLIENT
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    System.out.println("no error");
                    //2. MAKE POST REQUEST TO GIVEN ipAddress
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ip);
                    System.out.println("no error2");

                    //String json = "";
                    //3. BUILD JSON OBJECT
                    //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    //jsonObject.accumulate("")
                    String json = "";//"{\"lights\": [{\"lightId\": 1, \"red\":242,\"green\":116,\"blue\":12, \"intensity\": 0.5}],\"propagate\": true}";
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
                    json = jsonObj.toString();
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));

                    //5. SET JSON to STRING ENTITY
//                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
//                    System.out.println("no error3");
//
//                    //6. SET HTTP POST ENTITY
//                    httpPost.setEntity(se);
//                    System.out.println("no error4");

                    //7. SET SOME HEADERS TO INFORM SERVER ABOUT THE TYPE OF CONTENT
//                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
//                    System.out.println("no error5");
//                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//                    System.out.println("no error6");
                    //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    //httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
                    //CloseableHttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                    //ERROR HERE
                    //8. EXECUTE POST REQUEST TO THE GIVEN IP ADDRESS
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    System.out.println("no error7");
//                    httpPost.completed();
//                    response2.close();

                    //9. RECEIVE RESPONSE AS inputStream
                    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    System.out.println("no error8");
                    //10. CONVERT inputStream to string
                    if(inputStream != null) {
                        result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                        System.out.println("no error9");
                    }
                    else
                        result = "Did not work!";

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }



if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .**add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)**
                .commit();
    } else {
        // Or set the fragment from restored state info
        mainFragment = **(MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);**
    }

    }
```

And just so you have it:
Here's my mainfragment.java code

```
package uva.cs4720.ms3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link MainFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link MainFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 *
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment MainFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static MainFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
//                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
//    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        return view;
    }
        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Weird. In MainFragment, just removing the import statement: 
import android.app.Fragment;

and adding this:
import android.support.v4.app.*;

solved it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I fixed it too. The imports can do such a big mess sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused because you were importing from two different classes. hence the incompatibility.

You had:

```
MainActivity - import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
MainFragment - import android.app.Fragment;
```

Correct Way:

```
MainActivity - import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
MainFragment - android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```