# Cannot resolve method add(*.: Facebook Login to Android App (Redux)

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

Exactly the same problem as [Cannot resolve method add(*.: Facebook Login to Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27132974/cannot-resolve-method-add-facebook-login-to-android-app)

However, I do not have `import android.app.Fragment;`. Instead, I have `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

Yet, it still yields the same error. Same for `import android.support.v4.app.*;`

EDIT: I'm using Android Studio 1.1, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to extend the MainFragment to Fragment. All good now.